# Is there out of the box support for namespaced Consumers in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit and have a project structure like this:

```
Api1 (Publisher)
   - (Instance 1) Publishes PersonCreatedEvent

Worker1 (Consumer)
   - (Instance 1) Consumes PersonCreatedEvent via PersonCreatedEventConsumer
   - (Instance 2) Consumes PersonCreatedEvent via PersonCreatedEventConsumer

Worker2 (Consumer)
   - (Instance 1) Consumes PersonCreatedEvent via PersonCreatedEventConsumer
   - (Instance 2) Consumes PersonCreatedEvent via PersonCreatedEventConsumer
```

My goal is to have `Api1` publish a `PersonCreatedEvent` where both `Worker1` and `Worker2` receive the message and process it round-robin based on how many instances are running.

When registering my Consumers in both `Worker1` and `Worker2` in the .NET Core DI Container with `busConfigurator.AddConsumer<PersonCreatedEventConsumer>`, I see that only a single queue called `PersonCreatedEvent` is created in RabbitMQ.

Considering that Messages work with namespaces in MassTransit, I expected the following queue names to be created:

```
Worker1.PersonCreatedEvent
Worker2.PersonCreatedEvent
```

Including namespaces also seems to be a sensible default. With the behavior I'm seeing, any class named `PersonCreatedEventConsumer` (even across projects) would start consuming the same queue.

I can fix this by manually specifying my endpoints in each `Worker` like so:

```
busConfigurator
    .AddConsumer<PersonCreatedEventConsumer>()
    .Endpoint(e => e.Name = typeof(PersonCreatedEventConsumer).FullName);
```

NOTE: Although specifying endpoints works, it seems that Exchanges are also created in RabbitMQ for my Consumers. Why is this? Shouldn't these endpoints just be queues since they are consumers?

Is there an out-of-the-box solution for namespaced Consumers, or should I just continue with the pattern I've been following with specifying my endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default endpoint name formatter does not include the namespace when formatting endpoint names, it only uses the type Name. Rather than specify an endpoint for every consumer, you can specify your own endpoint name formatter, either by adding it to the container, or specifying explicitly when calling `ConfigureEndpoints`.

The [source](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Configuration/Definition/DefaultEndpointNameFormatter.cs#L16) for the DefaultEndpointNameFormatter should give you a good head start.

> As to your note, refer to the [broker topology](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html#broker-topology) section of the documentation to understand how MassTransit configures RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing work on MassTransit. I'm blown away with the project.